# Factorisation of numbers

Tags: logarithms, factoring

If $2000$ can be represented in the form of $a^a * b^b$, what is the least possible value of $a*b$? As a hint the answer is between $0-99$. I have tried logarithm but I am not getting how to proceed.

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ required to be whole numbers?

Comment: Prime factorization: $2000 = 2^4 \cdot 5^3$. If $a$ and $b$ are whole numbers, then one of them must contain $5$ as a factor, to make $2000$. But then its power contains $5^5$, which is already greater than $2000$. So there is no solution in whole numbers.

Comment: @ Mr e man - not necessarily

Answer (score 0):

Let $a\rightarrow0^+$.
Thus, $a^a\rightarrow1$ and $ab\rightarrow0^+$.

Id est, the minimum does not exist.

Comment: Can you be clear what I want to say?

Comment: You can say: what is infimum of $ab$? If so then the answer is $0$.